# Getting object variable using string + variable

Tags: php, variables, syntax

I would like to do something like this:
`echo $myObject->value_$id` but I don't know proper syntax and I'm not sure if it is possible.

`$id` is some PHP variable, for example has value 1. In the end, I would like to get `$myObject->value_1` but the number part (`1`) should be dynamic.

Comment: I'm curious how to do this in way using `->`

Comment: `$myObject->myArray["element"];` or `$myObject->myArray[$id];`. I think using arrays is a better way to do this anyways. But, what exactly do you want to do?

Comment: Ah, ok, now I understand that 'array thing' you were talking about

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The feature is called [variable properties](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php#example-107):

```
<?php

$myObject = (object)NULL;
$myObject->value_1 = 'I am value nr 1';

$id = 1;
echo $myObject->{"value_$id"};
```

Comment: I have never seen before casting NULL to an object ^^ Interesting idea ;-)

Comment: @Armin - Hang around StackOverflow for a while and you'll see weirder things :)

Comment: Been writing PHP for quite a while and haven't seen this done before.  You learn something new every day I suppose.  Thank you very much for this knowledge. :)

Answer (score 5):

This works:

```
$variableName = 'value_whatever_1337';
echo $myObject->$variableName;
```

Comment: And can't I join variable and string in the second line somehow?

Comment: You could, but this is not the recommended way if you want to keep your code clear and easy to read!

Answer (score 4):

```
$name = "value_" . $id;
echo $myObject->$name;
```

Comment: And can't I join variable and string in the second line somehow?