# Echo some properties value from a class with a for statement

Tags: php, class, object, properties, echo

I'm a newbie in here, especially on php, and I need your help.

I have a class that I've extended on the `value` class<.

In that class I've stored some of properties and I want to print it on the `for` statement.

Here is my code,

```
class value extends bla{
    public function example(){
        $value_bla[1] = $this->value1_bla;
        $value_bla[2] = $this->value2_bla;
        $value_bla[3] = $this->value3_bla;
        $value_bla[4] = $this->value4_bla;
        $value_bla[5] = $this->value5_bla;

        for( $i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++){
            echo 'the value is: '.$value_bla[$i]."\n";
        }
}

$example = new value();
$example->example();
```

but I want my code simpler like this,

```
class value extends bla{
    public function example(){  
        for( $i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++){
            echo 'the value is: '.$this->value.$i._bla."\n";
        }
}

$example = new value();
$example->example();
```

Unfortunately it is bring me an error

Can somebody tell me how to make that simpler code works?

Comment: In the second php code snippet where you have set the value you are trying to echo?

Comment: `$this->{'value'.$i.'_bla'}` - your values also start at 1 and your loop starts at 0, but maybe that's just a typo in your example code?

Comment: it's on my second "bla" class that i've extends it on the value class, yes it's a typo

Comment: Why not simply store it in an array in the first place, e.g. `$this->bla['value1']` or `$this->properties['bla']['value1']`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting object variable using string + variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8657541/getting-object-variable-using-string-variable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use curly braces if you want to to reference a variable using a variable ([Check the documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)):

```
class value extends bla{
    public function example(){  
        for( $i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++){
            echo 'the value is: '.$this->{'value'.$i.'_bla'}."\n";
        }
}
```

Although, when you find yourself doing this, there's probably a better way. You could, for example, use an associative array in your `bla` class which makes much more sense.

Comment: Hi Thank you for Ogeez and Emissary, your code it's works perfectly! :)

Comment: hi i've got some trouble again, `$i = 1` (in for statement) `echo 'bla'. $i - 1 .'bla';` but it's only print `-1` i've tried using the brackets but it's still give me an error